# Adobe Flex Project: Buttons seem to be calling wrong methods

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, button, actionscript

When I run this code, if I click the 'testExportToCSV' button, the application executes as expected ['save file to...' window opens]. However, once I click that button, the other two buttons then somehow trigger the same window ['save file to...'] to open as if I had clicked the 'testExportToCSV' button. Whilst debugging the application, I learned that the other two buttons are indeed entering into the correct click handling method although somehow end up executing the function 'writeCSV(event:MouseEvent)' which is declared inside the function 'WriteToOut()' which is only called when the 'testExportToCSV' button is clicked.

Please explain why this is happening

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                   minWidth="955" minHeight="601"
                   backgroundColor="#3b5998" 
                   creationComplete="windowedapplication1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import mx.rpc.http.HTTPService;

        protected function windowedapplication1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {}

        /** ########    Click Handlers    ######## */
        protected function csvButton_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
            trace("...inside csvButton_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent) ");
            textBox.text = "In Export to csv method";
            writeToOut();
        }
        protected function queryServer_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
            trace("...inside queryServer_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent) ");
            textBox.text = "In query server method";
            serviceRequest.url = "https://msppluto.com/Planholders_Flex.php?customerId=15";
            serviceRequest.send();
        }
        protected function refresh_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
            trace("...inside refresh_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent) ");
            textBox.text = "In refresh method";
            validateNow();
        }

        /** ########    Write to ...    ######## */
        protected function writeToOut():void{
            var myArray:Array = [];

            for(var i:int = 0; i < 100; i++)
                myArray[i] = {a:Math.random()*100, b:Math.random()*100, c:Math.random()};

            var csv:String = '';

            for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                csv += myArray[i].a + ',' + myArray[i].b + ',' + myArray[i].c + '/n';

            stage.doubleClickEnabled = true;
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, writeCSV);

            // why is this method being called when I click a different
            // button ?????????????????????????????????????????
            function writeCSV(event:MouseEvent):void{
                var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
                var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                bytes.writeUTFBytes(csv);
                file.save(bytes, 'test.csv');
            }
        } // end writeToOut

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <s:HTTPService
        id="serviceRequest"
        url="https://msppluto.com/Planholders_Flex.php"
        useProxy="false">
    </s:HTTPService>
</fx:Declarations>

<s:Label id="headline" text="HTTP Service" fontSize="45" x="10" y="10" color="#FFFFFF"></s:Label>
<s:Button id="testExportToCSV" x="14" y="187" minWidth="110" label="Export to csv" click="csvButton_clickHandler(event)"/>
<s:Button id="queryServerButton" x="14" y="216" minWidth="110" label="Query Server" click="queryServer_clickHandler(event)"/>
<s:Button id="refreshScreen" x="14" y="245" minWidth="110" label="refresh" click="refresh_clickHandler(event)"/> 
<s:TextInput id="textBox" x="197" y="216" widthInChars="25"  />

<mx:DataGrid id="dataGridForServiceRequest" x="575" y="160"
    dataProvider="{serviceRequest.lastResult.planHolders.planHolder}">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="User ID" dataField="userid"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="User Name" dataField="username"/>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know what is the context of the problem. But the problem is with the line
 stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, writeCSV);

You can make it

testExportToCSV.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, writeCSV);

and that too you have to place the above statement in creation complete event handler and bring the function outside writeOut function., otherwise it will not execute for the first time

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much! That solved my problem. If it's not too much trouble, could you explain what was happening (why was that particular function unexpectedly called?).

Comment: When you call `stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, writeCSV);`, any click *on the entire stage* will trigger `writeCSV`.  Since your other buttons are on the stage, the click event will trigger both listeners.